# Why is timing in java affected when opening a web browser?

Tags: java, swing, timer, plot, timing

In a time sensitive application in java, I am trying to plot data every 100ms. I have tried calling the plotting code in 3 different ways:

1) Inside a method within the code
2) Inside a timer set to 100ms
3) Inside a different thread

With all 3 techniques timing is unstable (varies between 90 – 110ms), but as soon as I open Firefox or Chrome and open a new tab, timing becomes quasi perfect (99 - 100 ms).

Why are web browsers affecting/improving timing? Can I modify my code to correct this issue and ensure 100ms (+/-1ms) timing?

Comment: I don't think this is a issue with Java, or that the browsers are doing something to stabilize your app.  I think the browsers are possibly causing just enough slowdown in the CPU that the scheduler is not being quite so enthusiastic about giving your app time to run.  I think this has to do with a combination of OS/CPU/JVM.  I would be interested to see if running any application that, say, created a 15% load would not have the same effect.

Comment: It isn't your code, it is your computer. Consider how this would run on one of those old Nokia phones (poorly) versus a nice modern computer (fairly accurate). There is not really an optimization (although some code as a demo would be nice to be sure) in your code you can make to fix those microsecond losses.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that the browser is using the CPU more, keeping it from falling into idle scheduling that can be less stable in terms of timing. You may consider doing some sort of work your application may want to do (or even useless work such as finding primes) in a low-priority thread in order to keep the CPU from falling into an idle state.

Comment: CPU processing speed is definitely the culprit here.

Comment: Or you can have you application sleep for some time, check to see if the total time is up, then sleep for the difference.  Sort of like "while I haven't slept for X, sleep for Y where Y = X - (nextWakeTime - currTime)".  I have even had apps where I kept an "average", would sleep for say 10% of the average, then calculated a "make-up" sleep to finish it off.

Answer (score 0):

Threads work with CPU time-slices, when you start your browser (or any other 'heavy' program) you are consuming more CPU, which should make the system more "alert" to how these time-slices are allocated.

Unfortunately, this kind of pends to a machine-level behavior so, code wise (on another layer of virtualization, i.e. the JVM), it's unlikely that it can be more precise than that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't guarantee that any particular time interval will be 100 milliseconds +- 1 millisecond.  However, you can average out the time discrepancies, as CodeChimp indicated in his comment.

You have to create a sleep loop, and you adjust the sleep time depending on how long it takes to get and plot your data.  If you're using Swing to plot the data, you have little control over when the plotting happens.

In some operating systems, System.currentTimeMillis isn't accurate to 1 millisecond.

Here's some timing code to illustrate what CodeChimp and I are talking about.

```
    public void timingLoop() {
        long constantSleepTime = 100L;
        boolean running = true;

        while(running) {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            getData();
            plotData();
            long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            long sleepTime = constantSleepTime - elapsedTime;
            // We have to sleep for a short time, even if sleep
            // time is negative.
            sleepTime = Math.max(sleepTime, 5L);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested it out and it definitely is not CPU related, running CPU hungry software didn’t make any difference. It is directly related to web browser most probably running in the background a Java Applet and affecting or keeping alive the VM.

I was able to solve the problem creating 2 different threads and synchronizing them, 1 thread for communication and another one for plotting, this way the application didn’t require such precision in timing so I could avoid playing around with time.

Finally, what it did make a huge difference is the way I was calculating the time. I was using System.currentTimeMillis() to read the time, I start using System.nanoTime() and this function is way more precise and does not get affected by web browser. Moral: when you need to measure time accurately try to use always System.nanoTime().